# При использовании API некорректно находит адрес

Tags: javascript, json, яндекс-карты

Имеется адрес "ДНП Усадьба Коровино, 173", при использовании карт на Yandex этот адрес корректно находится и отображется [правильный дом](https://yandex.ru/maps/1/moscow-and-moscow-oblast/house/dnp_usadba_korovino_173/Z08Ydg9lQEcAQFtvfXhzdHRgYA==/?ll=36.085927%2C55.425834&utm_source=main_stripe_big&z=17.51).

С другой стороны при [использовании API](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/?from=mapsapi) из официально документации мы получаем совершенно другой результат в поиске и отправляемся на другой адрес.

Подскажите пожалуйста, возможно это решается настройками?

Comment: Когда вводите этот адрес в поисковик, то там выходит 2 результата. Ни один из них вам не подходит?

Comment: Ни один из них не совпадает с правильным результатом к сожалению второй адрес находится ещё дальше от фактического.

Comment: Вы [этим](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/suggest.html#suggest__param-options) пользуетесь?

Comment: Вот такой код:
const options = {
            boundedBy: window.geoBounds,
            strictBounds: true,
        };
        ymaps.suggest(request.term, options).then((data) => {
            return data.map((item, i) => ({
                label: item.value,
                value: item.value,
                id: i,
            }));
        })

Answer (score 1):

Такс, вот мой пример. Находит то что нужно, пытался воспроизвести максимально близко к вашим условиям. У меня только нет `boundedBy` и подозреваю, что вы неправильно ограничиваете область

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <title>Быстрый старт. Размещение интерактивной карты на странице</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?apikey=0a42236a-42d2-4c87-affb-99b676f637e9&lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    ymaps.ready(init);

    function init() {

      document.querySelector('#suggest').addEventListener('input', (e) => {
        ymaps.suggest(e.target.value.trim(), {
          strictBounds: true,
        }).then(function(items) {
          console.clear();
          console.log(`Founded ${items.length} items`, items);
        });
      });
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <input id="suggest" value="ДНП Усадьба Коровино, 173">
  <div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div>
</body>

</html>
```